# BinaryFormatter Serialize Alternative c#

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

Code

```
private MemoryStream serialize_to_stream(String str)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, str);
        return stream;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to stop using BinaryFormatter and want to achieve the same result without using BinaryFormatter. Suggest me the Alternatives serialization method which provides the MemoryStream

Comment: He he you are using binarny formater for string? Why don't you just choose encoding(let's say utf8) and save the string into stream with this encoding?

Comment: Do you want something that is *backward compatible* with binaryFormatter? Or just something that serializes to a stream?

Comment: [MemoryPack](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack) or [MessagePack](https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp) NuGet package, perhaps? But that's not really useful for plain strings!

Comment: What are you doing with the `MemoryStream` after?

Comment: The problem here is: it sounds like you just want an alternative to the `BinaryFormatter`. That's in itself ok because reasons... But _with it_ you also need to let go of the binary format**ting**. To help you with _that_ we need more info about the context.

Comment: @Selvin I can try your suggestion. 
JonasH Need to serialize  into MemoryStream.
GoodNightNerdPride There is an API that expects input in format MemoryStream 

There is another use case where input is not string. 
It is Dictionary<String, MemoryStream> dictionary

Comment: See e.g. [Is there a high performance way to replace the BinaryFormatter in .NET5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64799591),  Though honestly if the only type you are converting to a byte array is a `string` without encoding, you could use [`MemoryMarshal.Cast<char, byte>(ReadOnlySpan<char> span)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast) to cast the char array to a byte array.

Comment: @Loch _"Need to serialize into MemoryStream."_ - Well, that's really unspecific. You can literally write anything to a memorystream that is expressible in a stream of bits ....